# Do margins care about relative/absolute position [CSS/SCSS]?

Tags: css, sass

I normally use relative positioning to center a div in its parent. I found that absolute positioning should also work. I am not certain what is making my div not centered. When a certain class is added to my div, it changes from relative to absolute positioning, but with the same type of margins:

```
#selectablesDiv{
    order: 1;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10vh auto 30vh auto;
    height: 45px;
    width: 465.94px;
    text-align: center;
    user-select: none;
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    &.aboutMeClicked{
        position: absolute;
        margin: 62vh auto 30vh auto;
    }
}
```

The parent div has the following CSS applied to it:

```
#homePageDiv{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: backgroundChange 36s ease-in-out 0s infinite;
}
```

Why do the right and left margins become size 0. It seems that the margins are based off of relative/absolute positioning, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `right : 0;` and `left: 0;` to center an absolute positioned element in it's parent (combined with `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;`).

```css
#homePageDiv {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: backgroundChange 36s ease-in-out 0s infinite;
    background-color: red;
}

#selectablesDiv {
    order: 1;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10vh auto 30vh auto;
    height: 45px;
    width: 465.94px;
    text-align: center;
    user-select: none;
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#selectablesDiv.aboutMeClicked {
       position: absolute;
       margin: 62vh auto 30vh auto;
       right: 0;
       left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="homePageDiv">
  <div id="selectablesDiv" class="aboutMeClicked"></div>
</div>
```